# Could I get some tips on describing this recursion language in English?

Tags: computer-science, recursion, computational-mathematics

I'm having a bit of trouble with this one. Here's the problem:

> Basis : $a \in L$
> Recursive definition : If $x \in L$, then $xb, xa$ and $bx$ are elements of $L$.

I get that strings which begin with **a** and end with **b** are in the language, and I also get that a set for the language would (roughly) appear as follows:

```
{a, ab, aa, ba, aab, aaa, baa, aaab, aaaa, baaa, …}
```

But I'm having issues with bringing this to a conclusive statement. Please help. Would something like, "**all strings within this language begin and end with either b or a**" work, or is that too simple?

I hope all of this is clear, and that I haven't made any mistakes with what I have so far.

Comment: Not every sequence that begins with $b$ is in the language. For instance $bb$

Comment: What is the alphabet of this language? Is it just $a$'s and $b$'s? If so, I believe the language is just the set of all words that contain at least one $a$. This can be proven with double containment, along with structural induction and normal induction.

Comment: @Snaw I'm a bit confused: how does 'bb' not begin with 'b'? Hope this doesn't sound rude.

Comment: @AlanAbraham The question specifically says: *The following language is defined recursively in {a, b}*.

Comment: @cae $bb$ will never appear.

Comment: @Gary Oh yeah, my mistake.